# How to Avoid MathJAX Typeset Queue Error when loading new data into DOM

Tags: javascript, mathjax

My website uses a javascript function to load (via AJAX) math markup into the DOM and then render it with MathJAX.

If the function is called a second time (i.e., to load some new math markup into a DOM element):

- All works well if MathJAX has finished processing its Typeset queue prior to the second function call.
- An error appears if MathJAX has NOT finished processing its Typeset queue prior to the second function call.

  `MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML&latest:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null`

Once the error occurs, MathJAX is in a bad state and will not function until entirely reloaded (e.g., via a page reload).

It seems like the easiest solution to this problem would be to clear the MathJAX Typeset queue before loading new math via AJAX, but I can find no method in the MathJAX API that clears the Typeset queue.

Here's a stripped-down version of the function (using jQuery syntax) I'm using:

```
window.loadNewMath = function() {
    // I want to clear the MathJAX Typeset queue before making the AJAX call

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/getNewMath",
        data: [],
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['success']) {
                // load math into DOM
                $("#math-panel").html(data.new_math);
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'math-panel']);
            } else {
                $("#math-panel").html('oops. there was a database error');
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#math-panel").html('oops. there was an ajax error');
        }
    })
}
```

This scenario seems like a common use case, so I hope someone can recommend a way of avoiding this error.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Received from MathJax Developer:

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2071